# Filling gaps with two conditions, closest existing data and same name

Tags: r, data

I'm working with a traffic dataset, with four main fields: name of the streets, intensity and lat-lon coordinates. So it is something like this (totally made up data)

```
street   IMD     lat     lon

a         27     41.423  2.121

a         NA     41.503  2.088

a         35     41.214  2.102

b         NA     40.231  2.484

b         13     40.235  2.471

b         29     40.254  2.814
```

I need to fill the NA data with the closest imd data, and also it must be the same street, so two conditions. And if there is a data already, don't do anything. I'm trying with "for" and "if" lines, but I'm totally lost. Of course we are talking about thousands of lines.

I've been looking for an answer for this but I've not found it... I'm still a beginner in R, but I'm doing my best.

Comment: And there might be more than one NA per street? And its possible the fill value might be different for each one, because the nearest non-missing point might be different?

Comment: yes, actually, for sure there are more than one NA per street (there about 16k sections and "only" about 2.5k with data). And about the second question, the point is that the filling should start everytime (or at least this is how I think it should work), so a gap is filled, and maybe that section is closest to the next gap, but anyway the data is the same that the first one (as long as we talk about the same street)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some data in a table:

```
> d
  street IMD    lat   lon
1      a  27 41.423 2.121
2      a  NA 41.503 2.088
3      a  35 41.214 2.102
4      b  NA 40.231 2.484
5      b  13 40.235 2.471
6      b  29 40.254 2.814
```

Copy it, use `sp` package for spatial data, make it spatial:

```
> library(sp)
> dd = d
> coordinates(dd)=~lon+lat
```

This function takes a point and a set of points, works out the distances from the point to all the points in the set, finds the one with the minimum distance, extracts the IMD from that point:

```
> nnp = function(p1,p2){
     dm = gDistance(p1,p2,byid=TRUE)
     pmin=which.min(dm)
     p2$IMD[pmin]}
```

Now we need to apply that over all missing values, selecting a target from all the points with the same street and non-missing IMD. Note this treats all missing values effectively simultaneously - finding the missing value for  `dd[1,]` doesn't mean that might get used to find the next missing value. I use an `lapply` loop:

```
> fills = unlist(lapply(which(is.na(dd$IMD)),
     function(i){
       d1 = dd[i,] # our missing point
       d2=dd[dd$street==d1$street,] # all points in that street
       d2=d2[!is.na(d2$IMD),] # minus the missing ones
       if(all(is.na(d2$IMD))){ # catch everything missing
        return(NA)
       }
       nnp(d1,d2) # return IMD of the nearest
     }))
> fills
[1] 27 13
```

That's the IMD values in the same order as they are missing, so replace them in the original data frame:

```
> d$IMD[is.na(d$IMD)]=fills
> d
  street IMD    lat   lon
1      a  27 41.423 2.121
2      a  27 41.503 2.088
3      a  35 41.214 2.102
4      b  13 40.231 2.484
5      b  13 40.235 2.471
6      b  29 40.254 2.814
```

This isn't tested thoroughly - check with something you can plot and make sure it does what you want. Corner cases may fail - for example streets with all missing values, or stuff like that.

Comment: wow, that was fast, I'm working on it and I'll let you know how it was. Thank you very much

Comment: so, it works perfect, thanks, but there's still a little issue. 
Sometimes, I have some streets with no data at all (let's say street "d") and in these cases, R is taking the closest data that even if it comes from a different street (a, b or c), which is wrong.

Comment: What do you want it to do in that case?

Comment: I've put a test in that catches that case, in which it returns NA for the fill value. There's probably a better way, by ignoring all streets with all NA values in IMD.

Comment: Yes, actually I was going to, first of all, extract the streets that have all NA's, and then run the scritpt. About  your test, it is returning me all NA's :/

Comment: It should return all NAs for locations on streets that don't have any non-NA data - it should still work correctly for streets with some non-NA data.

Comment: I don't know why, but is not working at all...if I understood well, it should return only streets with some NA data (a,b,c in the example), and don't return streets with all NA (the "d" street I said in a comment), right? at least this is what I'm trying to do. Anyway I'm working with the other option, which is previously removing those streets that does not have any IMD data.  BTW, you're being very patient, thanks a lot!